# Run C# UrlEncode String in HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, urlencode

I need to URL encode an email address. If I do this (without URL encode), it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://www.example.com/reset-password?e=%7bEMAILADDRESS%7d">
</body>
</html>
```

The email address is printed raw, not URL-encoded.

What I'd really like to do is the following, but `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` doesn't execute:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://www.example.com/reset-password?e=HttpUtility.UrlEncode("%7bEMAILADDRESS%7d")">
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions on how to execute HttpUtility.UrlEncode() for usage in the above manner? Thanks for any help.

Comment: For more information on inline expressions in asp.net.... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/inline-expressions

Answer (score 3):

You need to use  `<%= %>`

like:

```
<a href="https://portal.nchinc.com/reset-password?e= 
 <%=HttpUtility.UrlEncode("%7bEMAILADDRESS%7d") %>"/>
```

The <%= ... %> is used when you need to display an expression.